# jquery ajax and php arrays

Tags: php, ajax, arrays, jquery

I am trying to submit some data to a PHP script, however the PHP scripts expects the data to arrive in a specific format, like this example which is a dump of the post,

```
Array ( [save] => Add to shortlist [cv_file] => Array ( [849709537] => Y [849709616] => Y [849709633] => Y ) )
```

The process is currently that a user selects the product they want using checkboxes and then clicks a submit button which fires the PHP scripts,

The HTML looks like this,

```
div class="row">

                        <ul>
                            <li class="drag_check ui-draggable">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="inp_cv_849709537" name="cv_file[849709537]" class="cv_choice" value="Y">
                            </li>

                            <li class="id"><a href="/search/cv/849709537">849709537</a></li>
                            <div class="disp">
                            <li class="location">Huddersfield</li>
                            <li class="status">
                            Not currently working                               </li>
                            <li class="education">other</li>
                            <li class="role">
                            Temporary                               </li>
                            <li class="salary">£100,000 or more</li>
                            <div class="s">&nbsp;</div>
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                            <dl>
                                <dt>Current Role</dt>
                                <dd>Developer </dd>
                                <dt>Sectors</dt><dt>
                                </dt><dd>
                                    Energy &amp; Utilities, Healthcare, Hospitality &amp; Travel, Installation &amp; Maintenance, Installation &amp; Maintenance                                    </dd>

                                <dt>About Me</dt><dt>
                                </dt><dd></dd>
                                </dl>
                                <div class="s"></div>
                    </div>
```

I am needing to use AJAX instead now, but I need to send the data to PHP in the format it expects here is what I have so far,

```
$('#addshortlist').click(function() {
var datastring = ui.draggable.children().attr('name')+"="+ui.draggable.children().val()+"&save=Add to shortlist";
alert(datastring);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/search',
    data:ui.draggable.children().attr('name')+"="+ui.draggable.children().val()+"&save=Add to shortlist",
    success:function(){
        alert("Success"+datastring);
    },
    error:function() {
        alert("Fail"+datastring);
    }
}); 
return false;
```

});

I would really appreciate any help

Comment: Can you modify your PHP script? If so you can pass your data as JSON and decode it in your PHP script

Answer (score 0):

To get the resulting PHP output, you need to assemble an object literal as below:

```
var your_data = {
    save: 'Add to shortlist',
    cv_array: {
        '849709537': 'Y',
        '849709616': 'Y',
        '849709633': 'Y'
    }
};
```

Then you can do this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/path/to/script.php',
    data: your_data,
    success: function(data){
        $('#debug').html(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

(Incidentally, The base HTML that would produce your output would be):

```
<form action="http://example.com/path/to/script.php" method="POST" id="myForm">
    <input name="save" value="Add to shortlist">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cv_array[849709537]" value="Y" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cv_array[849709616]" value="Y" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cv_array[849709633]" value="Y" checked>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue &rarr;">
</form>
```

Now, if you've not changed your form, all you really need to do is make the ajax call, and the data you pass would be assembled with jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method, which rolls up all the content of a form into something you can pass to a server-side script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com/path/to/script.php',
    data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
    success: function(data){
        $('#debug').html(data);
    },
    dataType: 'html'
});
```